# How do I install sandbox module 'Filedepot multiupload'?

Tags: files

I am new to Drupal and I am unable to install the sandbox module called [Multiupload](https://www.drupal.org/node/2319451), it is an add-on module for [Filedepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) but there are no installation instructions that I can see. I am unsure where to put the files.

Steps I have taken so far:

1. Installed filedepot and it is working.
2. Installed plupload.
3. Overwritten `filedepot-mainpage.tpl.php` with the multiupload version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link you provided](https://www.drupal.org/node/2319451) for the sandbox module 'Filedepot Multiupload' is actually an issue (request) for [Drupal.org Project Applications](https://www.drupal.org/project/projectapplications).

The actual sandbox project is located at https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/e.ruiter/2290395 . On that page, wihin resources, there isn't any link mentioned (yet) with title "Read documentation", which typically points to either available "Community documentation", or to the "Readme.txt" that comes with the module.

The module's `Readme.txt` appears to be the best documentation currently available. To review/browse it, you have 2 options:

1. Browse the module's source code that you downloaded, which should contain that readme.txt.
2. Follow the "[Browse code repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-e.ruiter-2290395)" on the project page of the sandbox project. Next visit the "[Tree](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-e.ruiter-2290395/tree/)" tab and click on the [Readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-e.ruiter-2290395/tree/README.txt) link there.

Here is the content of that readme.txt:

> - **Introduction**: This module extends the filedepot module with multiple upload support. Files can be uploaded with the plupload module which supports drag and drop.
> - **Installation**: Just install the module by copying the module to site/all/modules directory or install with drush. If you get some errors about files missing and plupload is not loading, you are probably missing the plupload library. Find the README file of the plupload module and follow the instructions.

**Note**: while you're reviewing the Readme.txt and experimenting / testing that module, consider either (or both) of these approaches:

- enhance the readme.txt with anything you learn/discover about it, and then contribute an updated version of readme.txt back to this sandbox project. E.g. by creating a documentation issue, and attaching a copy of the updated readme.txt.
- create a community page containing such documentation, and then create a documentation issue for this sandbox project, requesting the module owner to update the project page to point to this new community documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer and I am sorry it took me so long to reply, your answer helped me to install the plugin but unfortunately the plugin itself caused too many conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Happy my answer helped somehow. Looks like you'll have to find an alternative module (referably not in sandbox status). Maybe post a new questions about that? If you do, make sure to add appropriate details in what kind of features you're lookiing for, what you tried, etc.